# Can't Create Site in Salesforce(18) - Classic

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, salesforce-service-cloud

- I want to use live agent Service, that I configured already.
- But I cant create new Custom chat page(because I cant see add **sites** functionality in my account)
  (I already add **domain** and **visualforce pages**)

Answer (score 0):

Please go to Setup and enter 'Sites' as a search query. Sites should show up. You might need to switch from Lightning Experience to classic SF, but I'm quite sure this isn't neccessary.